# External Function as Function argument

Tags: solidity, remix, bytecode, function-selector, function-pointer

I am trying to figure out how the calldata looks, when I pass a function as a function argument.

For example,
function foo(function(uint) external callback) external {}

I assume it is the methodId of foo(function) and the argument as bytecode would be the methodId of the function that I gave as an argument, but in remix, it doesnt work this way.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Function types are of two variants, `internal` and `external`.

`internal` type can only be passed to `internal` functions. So they're not part of the ABI and the compiler simply `JUMP`s to the internal function when used inside.

`external` functions can be passed to only `public` or `external` functions.

When `function takeExternalFuncAsParam(function(uint) external callback) public` is called outside of solidity context, i.e `ethersJS`, the ABI encodes the function type as `bytes24` where the **first 20 bytes is the address to invoke the function on** and the **next 4 bytes is the function selector.**

When `function takeExternalFuncAsParam(function(uint) external callback) public` is called in solidity context i.e from inside same contract, you can directly pass in the function and can also access members like `callback.address` and `callback.selector` which are the address of contract to call and the 4 byte selector.